# spring 2.0 findbugs nullable throws error even when wrapped in null check

Tags: spring, spring-boot, findbugs

I'm having difficulty with Findbugs complaining about springs `HttpEntity.getBody()`.

Below you'll see I call `response.getBody().length`, which I understand could cause a NPE.  However when I wrap it in  `if (response.getBody() != null)`, it still complains.  It only does this in Spring 2.0 (not 1.5) which appears to be related to the `@Nullable` annotation added to the method.

Can I get an explanation why even when I wrap it in a null check, it still complains when I get the length of it?

Bug type `NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE`

```
ResponseEntity<SomeClass[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(someUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,
                SomeClass[].class);
for (int i = 0; response.getBody().length > i;   i++) {
                        doSomething()
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Spot bugs documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html)  the reason for this occuring is :

'The return value from a method is dereferenced without a null check, and the return value of that method is one that should generally be checked for null. This may lead to a NullPointerException when the code is executed.'

fixed it by:

```
Optional <T> body = Optional.ofNullable(response.getBody);
if (body.isPresent()) {
   //use body
}
```

You are getting the warning because getBody method has been annotated as Nullable and spotBugs / findbugz expects that an explicit null checker be made before using the value. Works well for me.

Comment: I wish I remember what we did, but i THINK we had to upgrade to Spotbugs (from findBugs), which is the successor.